# Advanced jQuery Popout Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Several problems:

1) I am trying to make this script run more efficiently.

2) When the user clicks either pop out button it opens a windows and hides the element. (Currently I am using .detach() to remove the embedded video player because in Firefox .toggle() just hides the player but keeps the audio playing. Is there a better way to do this?

3) In theory by clicking the button again or closing the window manually it should un hide or .toggle() the element but does not for the video player due to detach().

4) If a user pops out the window manually closes it and then pops it out again to only close it once more the element does not .toggle() back.

See it in action here, http://www.mst3k.tv/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lights').click(function(){$('#darkness').fadeToggle(500);});
  $("#lights").toggle(function(){$("#lights").attr('id','lightsoff');},function(){$("#lightsoff").attr('id','lights');});
  /**VIDEO**/
  var videoWin;
  $('#video-toggle').click(function(){
      $('#video').fadeToggle(500);
      $('#video').detach();
      });
  $('#video-toggle').click(function(){
      if (videoWin && !videoWin.closed) {
        videoWin.close();
        return false;
      }
      videoWin = window.open(
        $(this).attr('rel'),
        'videoWin',
        'width=600,height=480,toolbar=0,top=0,left=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1');
      return false;
      }
    );
  var watchVideo = setInterval(function() {
      if (videoWin.closed) {clearTimeout(watchVideo);$('#video').show(500)}
      return false;
   }, 1);
  /**CHAT**/
  var chatWin;
  $('#chat-toggle').click(function(){
      $('#chat').fadeToggle(500);
      /*$('#chat').detach();*/
      });
  $('#chat-toggle').click(function(){
      if (chatWin && !chatWin.closed) {
        chatWin.close();
        return false;
      }
      chatWin = window.open(
        $(this).attr('rel'),
        'chatWin',
        'width=320,height=480,toolbar=0,top=0,left=601,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1');
      return false;
      }
    );
  var watchChat = setInterval(function() {
      if (chatWin.closed) {clearTimeout(watchChat);$('#chat').show(500)}
      return false;
   }, 1);
  /*$("a.btn").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: "6px", maxFontSize: "14px" });*/
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you created a jQuery plugin for your code so you can re-use it and avoid DRY. Here are a couple of options:

Plugin 1: [jQuery popupWindow](http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html)

Plugin 2: [jQuery winPop](http://github.com/vasilionjea/winPop)

Also note that the `closed` property is not part of any W3C specification, however it might be supported across Browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a JS function that could be reused. According to the [w3cschools website](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp) the *window.closed* property is supported in most major browsers and you can check for it prior to triggering the event.

instead of

```
if(videoWin && !videoWin.closed)
```

you could use

```
if (typeof videoWin!='undefined'){ /* it has been created */}
elseif(typeof videoWin='undefined') { /*it's okay to open the new window*/}
```

Make sure you're not creating the variable if you're using this as a check though until the window open event has been fired. Since you're creating the var a couple of lines above your function declaration it will always return as defined.

You'll need to specify a target object in your function to have it throw multiple windows correctly... meaning you can't declare one var for multiple windows. Maybe a class would be better.

Something I thought was odd earlier but forgot to mention before FB posted my response prematurely was that you're adding your *href* in the *rel* attribute and specifying the href as a js:void(0) which is also non-standard. The rel attribute is for specifying the relationship between the link and the page... (eg. rel=nofollow). That might also be why it's not firing and misfiring some of the time as well, and the differences between browser response.